# Keep track of string matches to create a new ID

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

This is the prompt

> Write a program that reads in a name and outputs an ID based on the name. The ID should be uppercase and formatted using the first three letters of the name and three digits starting at 005. The digits should be incremented by 5 if an ID already exists.

This is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class substring_match {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int id = 5;
    int repeatId = 5;
    int nameCount = 1;
    String[] nameArray = new String[5];
    String name;
    String subName = null;

    for (int i = 0; i<nameArray.length; i++){
        name = scan.nextLine();
        subName = name.substring(0, 3);
        nameArray[i] = subName;
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < nameArray.length; x++){
        if(nameArray[x].substring(0, 3) == subName.substring(0,3)){
            nameCount = nameCount + 1;
            System.out.println("nameCount " + nameCount);
            repeatId = nameCount * id;
            if(repeatId == 5){
                System.out.println(nameArray[x].toUpperCase() + "00" + repeatId);
            }else{ // if repeatId is 10 or higher, won't need the extra 0
                System.out.println(nameArray[x].toUpperCase() + "0" + repeatId);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println(nameArray[x].substring(0, 3).toUpperCase() + "00" + id);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably consider doing this another way...

```
Have an empty hashmap<String sub, int multiplier>
Read in the name
Generate the subname
Fetch from or create subname in hashmap
  If new, set multiplier to 1
  If exists, increment multiplier
Return String.format(“%s%3d”, subname, multiplier x 5).toUpperCase()
```

I would give you code but writing the above was hard enough on an iPad